# Boolean function to print out string if there are entries higher than 90

Tags: c++, arrays, search, boolean

I'm trying to write a program that allows users to enter in an amount of their choosing. I want the numbers displayed in ascending order and have the average displayed. I got this part done, but i also want to have a string printed out if there is at least one number higher than 90 and another string if there is not a number higher than 90. I think im pretty close to making this work, but whenever I run it though the compiler, it says that the boolean function that I have to use does not take 1 arguments. I really don't know what to do.

```
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std; 
#include <iomanip>  
#include <cstdlib>

int compare(const void* pa, const void* pb) 
{ 
  const int& a = *static_cast<const int*>(pa); 
  const int& b = *static_cast<const int*>(pb); 
  if (a < b) return -1; // negative if a<b 
  if (a > b) return 1; // positive if a>b 
  return 0; // 0 for tie 
} // compare 

double getAverage(int* score, int n) 
{ 
  int sum = 0; 
  int i = 0; 
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) 
    sum += score[i]; 
  double average = double(sum) / n; 
  return average; 
} // getAverage 
//Boolen Function to see if there are A grades present 
bool getAGrades(int* score, int n) 
{ 
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++){
        if (score[i] >= 90){
            return true;
            cout << "there is at least one A"<<endl;
         }else {
             return false;
             cout<<" No A Grades "<<endl;
         }
    }
}
int main() 
{  
    int size;
    cout << "How many scores? ";
    cin >> size;
    cin.ignore(1000, 10);
    int* score = new int[size];  

    int i; // loop counter 
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) 
    { 
        cout<< "Enter a number: ";
        cin >> score[i]; 
        cin.ignore(1000, 10); 
    } // for 

    qsort(score, size, sizeof(int), compare); 
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        cout << score[i] << ' ';
    }
    cout <<endl;
    cout << "Lowest score  = " << score[0] << endl;
    cout << "Highest score = " << score[size-1] << endl;
    cout << fixed << setprecision(1);
    cout << "Average = " << getAverage(score, size) << endl; 
    //this is where i want it to print if there are a grades or not
    getAGrades(score);

    return 0; 
} // main
```

Comment: That's supposed to be C++ ? Use `std::sort` and `std::vector`..

Comment: Can you please copy the verbatim compiler error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
bool getAGrades(int* score, int n)
```

getAGrades requires two arguments - score and n.

```
getAGrades(score);
```

When you call getAGrades, you only pass in one argument. You should also pass in an argument for n.

```
getAGrades(score, size);
```

Your getAGrades function body also has some errors. Suppose you passed in an array [1,100]. In the first iteration of your for loop, it sees that score[0] == 1, so it returns false. It never gets to score[1] to see that it is above 90. For this reason, you should delay returning false until after you have iterated over the entire array.

```
bool getAGrades(int* score, int n) 
{ 
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++){
        if (score[i] >= 90){
            return true;
            cout << "there is at least one A"<<endl;
        }   
    }
    return false;
    cout<<" No A Grades "<<endl;
}
```

One more thing - your cout statements occur after you return a value, so they never get executed. You should put them before the return statements.

```
bool getAGrades(int* score, int n) 
{ 
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++){
        if (score[i] >= 90){
            cout << "there is at least one A"<<endl;
            return true;
        }   
    }
    cout<<" No A Grades "<<endl;
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, your question: The function `getAGrades` takes an `int* score`, and a `int n`.  The last thing you do before you return from `main` is call `getAGrades(score);`, but you don't give it a size.  You have to also pass the size: `getAGrades(score, size)`.

Second: why does your compare function take `void*`?  That's dangerous for no reason.  Why aren't you using the type-safe `std::sort` with a safe comparison function?

Third: `getAGrades` returns right before each `cout`, so it will never ever display anything.  It should `cout`, and *then* return.
Edit: [Keven](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8524711/845092) also noticed that `getAGrades` returns when it finds a grade that isn't an A.  As he explained, such a function should return when it finds an A grade, or if it checked *ALL* of the grades without finding any.  Remove the `"No A Grades"` block to *after* the for loop.

Fourth: Your `cin.ignore` doesn't do anything useful, since you only have formatted input.  Also, use `'\n'` instead of `10`, otherwise you're going to confuse people, and it's more portable.

Fifth: Prefer standard containers to allocating your own arrays.  Because your code leaks the `score` array.

Comment: so 'getAGrades(score, size);'

Answer (score 1):

Use `std::sort` and `std::vector`.
I know it's not really the answer to this problem.
But when you want to use C++ you shouldn't try to use these C-functions like `qsort`.
With `std::sort` you can sort c arrays too.

`qsort(score, size, sizeof(int), compare);` becomes `std::sort(score, score+size);` (or `std::sort(score, score+size, compare);`)

C++ way (use of `std::vector` and `std::sort`, with fixed `getAGrades` function):

```
 #include <iostream> 
 #include <iomanip>
 #include <vector>
 #include <algorithm>  

 using namespace std;

 double getAverage(const vector<int>& score) 
 { 
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < score.size(); ++i)
    {
        sum += score[i];
    }
    return sum / double(score.size()); 
 }


 bool getAGrades(const vector<int>& score) 
 { 
     for (int i = 0; i < score.size(); ++i)
     {
         if (score[i] >= 90)
         {
            cout << "there is at least one A"<<endl;
            return true;
         }
     }
     cout << "No A Grades"<<endl;
     return false;
 }

 int main() 
 {  
     int size;

     cout << "How many scores? ";
     cin >> size;
     cin.ignore(1000, 10);

     vector<int> score(size);

     for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) 
     { 
         cout<< "Enter a number: ";
         cin >> score[i]; 
         cin.ignore(1000, 10); 
     }

     sort(score.begin(), score.end());
     for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
     {
         cout << score[i] << ' ';
     }
     cout <<endl;
     cout << "Lowest score  = " << score[0] << endl;
     cout << "Highest score = " << score[size-1] << endl;
     cout << fixed << setprecision(1);
     cout << "Average = " << getAverage(score) << endl; 

     getAGrades(score);

     return 0; 
 }
```